# Evaluate infinite hyperbolic series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathrm{sech}((2n-1)\pi)$

Tags: modular-forms, elliptic-integrals, theta-functions

Could anyone show me a solution how to approach this series? According to this
[blog](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/01/elementary-approach-to-modular-equations-ramanujan-theory-4.html) I doubt that we could be using $$\theta_{2}^{2}(q^2)=4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{q^{(2n+1)}}{1+q^{(4n+2)}}$$ and let $\frac{K’}{K}=1$ So $k$ and $k’ =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

But I don’t know about Theta function much ,what’s related to
$$\theta_{2}^{2}(q^2)~,$$ and I’m quite new to this function.Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Numerics suggests that it is approximately equal to $\frac{2e^{-\pi}}{1+e^{-2\pi}}.$

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc that is simply because your value equals $\operatorname{sech}(\pi)$, the first term in this series, and $\operatorname{sech}(x)$ rapidly decays so the first term is dominant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My blog post linked in the question gives the key formula which can be used to evaluate the sum in question in closed form.

The relevant formula is $$\vartheta_{2}^{2}(q)=4\sqrt{q}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{q^n}{1+q^{2n+1}}\tag{1}$$ It is best to give some details about the key players in the formula above and we start with the basics.

Let $k\in(0,1)$ and $k'=\sqrt{1-k^2}$. The number $k$ is called *elliptic modulus* and $k'$ is called *complementary* (to $k$) modulus. Based on these parameters we define *complete elliptic integral of first kind* $$K(k) =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}}\tag{2}$$ The numbers $K(k), K(k') $ are usually denoted by $K, K'$ if the corresponding value of $k$ is evident from context.

It is almost [magical](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2010/10/the-magic-of-theta-functions.html?m=0) that given the values of $K, K'$ the value of $k$ can be obtained via functions of a variable $q=e^{-\pi K'/K} $ (called *nome* corresponding to $k$). Let's then define Jacobi's *theta functions*
\begin{align}
\vartheta_{2}(q)&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{(n+(1/2))^2}\tag{3a}\\
\vartheta_{3}(q)&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{n^2}\tag{3b}
\end{align}
and then we have the identities $$\vartheta_{3}^{2}(q)=\frac{2K}{\pi}, \, k=\frac{\vartheta_{2}^{2}(q)}{\vartheta_{3}^{2}(q)}\tag{4}$$
The formula $(1)$ and the above identity $(4)$ can be proved using definitions $(2),(3a),(3b)$ but the proofs are non-trivial and non-obvious.

---

Coming back to the sum in question, let's write $q=e^{-\pi} $ and the sum in question is equal to $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{q^{2n+1}+q^{-(2n+1)}}=2q\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{q^{2n}}{1+q^{4n+2}}=\frac{\vartheta_{2}^{2}(q^2)}{2}\tag{5}$$ From $(4)$ we have $$\vartheta_{2}^{2}(q)=\frac{2kK}{\pi}$$ Next we have [Landen transformation](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/01/elliptic-functions-landens-transformation.html?m=0) which allows us to replace $q$ by $q^2$ and accordingly replace $k$ by $(1-k')/(1+k')$ and $K$ by $(1+k')K/2$. And therefore we have $$\vartheta_{2}^{2}(q^2)=\frac{(1-k')K}{\pi}\tag{6}$$ Now using $(5),(6)$ we get our sum as $(1-k')K/(2\pi)$. For $q=e^{-\pi} $ we have $K=K'$ so that $k=k'=1/\sqrt{2}$ and $K=\dfrac{\Gamma^2(1/4)}{4\sqrt{\pi}}$ and we get the desired closed form evaluation of the sum in question.

Answer (score 2):

I'll sketch why there is a closed-form for those kind of special values of modular forms.

- From that $sech(\pi t)$ is its own Fourier transform, with the Poisson summation formula show that $f(z) = \sum_n sech(2i \pi z)$ is a modular form of weight $1$ for $\Gamma_0(4)$.
- We want to evaluate $f(i/2)$, equivalently $f(8i)$ using the modularity. Let $g(z) = \frac{f(8z)^{12}}{\Delta( z)}$, it is weight $0$ modular of level $4.8$ and it is in the function field of $X_0(32)$, with no poles on the upper-half plane and it has integer coefficients. Thus $P(z,T) = \prod_{d| 32, b \bmod d} (T-g(\frac{\frac{32}d z+b}{d})) = p(j(z),T)$ with $p  \in \Bbb{Q}[X,Y]$. The coefficients of that polynomial are found from the first few coefficients of
  $g(\frac{\frac{32}d z+b}{d})$ at $i\infty$.
- Together with $j(i) = 1728$ we find that $g(i)$ is a root of $p(1728,T)\in \Bbb{Q}[T]$. We can factorize this polynomial to find the minimal polynomial of $g(i)$.
- Finally from the isomorphism given by Weierstrass functions from complex tori to elliptic curves we find $\Delta(i)$ is given in term of the integral $\int_C \frac{dx}{y}=\int_\infty^0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+x}}dx+\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{-\sqrt{x^3+x}}dx$ on the elliptic curve $y^2=  x^3+x$, and the latter integrals reduce to the $\beta(.,.)$ function and to $\Gamma(1/4)$, obtaining that $\Delta(i ) = (2\pi)^{-6} \Gamma (1/4)^{24}$.

  Whence we have found the minimal polynomial of $f(8i)^{12} (2\pi)^6 \Gamma(1/4)^{-24}$ and a radical expression for it, **ie. a closed-form**, because that polynomial is radical.

Comment: From there you can try to implement the needed algorithm to find the polynomial and factorize it, but you'll probably have some troubles because it is large, thus you'll need some tables of modular forms and their particular values (in order to split the computation into several simpler steps with smaller polynomials).

Answer (score 1):

$$ \eqalign{\text{sech}((2n-1)\pi) &= \frac{2}{\exp((2n-1)\pi) + \exp(-(2n-1)\pi)}\cr
&= \frac{2 \exp(-(2n-1)\pi)}{1 + \exp(-2(2n-1)\pi)}\cr &= 2 \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^{j} \exp(-(2j+1)(2n-1)\pi)}$$
so that
$$ \eqalign{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \text{sech}((2n-1)\pi) &= 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \exp(-(2j+1)(2n-1)\pi)\cr
&= 2 \sum_{m=0}^\infty f(2m+1) \exp(-(2m+1)\pi)} $$
where $f(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$ that are congruent to $1$ mod $4$ minus the number of divisors congruent to $3$ mod $4$.  Note that $f(n)=0$ if $n \equiv 3 \mod 4$.

Answer (score 0):

According to a CAS
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \text{sech}((2n-1)\pi)=-\frac{\pi+i \left(\psi
   _{e^{2 \pi }}\left(\frac{2+i}{4}\right)- \psi _{e^{2 \pi }}\left(\frac{2-i}{4}\right)\right) }{2 \pi }$$ where appears [the q-digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html).